# Applying for ITIN with tax return

Tags: united-states, taxes, itin

I understand that I need to send my tax return forms with the W-7 to the IRS if my spouse does not have an ITIN. My question might be stupid, but after I do this my taxes are considered filed right? In other words, I am simultaneously applying for ITIN and filing my tax returns right?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it, you file your completed 1040 (or variant) and the rest of your tax-return forms along with the W-7 (and supporting documentation), along with any payment if not getting a refund, and you are set. No need to file your return separately also. Then next year you'll have the ITIN to use on your tax return.

Note that on years you're filing Form W-7 you don't mail your return to the address in the 1040 instructions, but to the address in the [W-7 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw7.pdf):

```
 Internal Revenue Service
 Austin Service Center
 ITIN Operation
 P.O. Box 149342
 Austin, TX 78714-9342
```